# Personalise the magnifying glass

Tags: r, googlevis

I use the googleVis package to plot a map of France which I embedded in a shiny app. But the thinner division is by regions and i have to represents departments also. I actually use .shp files to plot and render each regions divided by departments, but I want to make my outputs more interactive and aesthetically pleasing.

Is there a way to force the magnifying glass when i hover over a region and to personalise the content of it (display a region map inside for example) ? Or to construct an equivalent.

Probaly not with R directly...

```
library(googleVis)
df <- data.frame(departement = c("Alpes-Maritimes", "Bouches-du-Rhone", "Rhone", "Savoie", "Haute-Savoie"), region =  c(rep("Provence-Alpes-Cote d'Azur", 2), rep("Rhone-Alpes", 3)),
ISO_3166.2 = c(rep("FR-U", 2), rep("FR-V", 3)), x = rnorm(5))
dfAggreg <- aggregate(df$x, by = list(region = df$region, iso = df$ISO_3166.2), sum)
plot(gvisGeoChart(dfAggreg,
         locationvar = "iso", colorvar = "x", hovervar = "region",
         options = list(region = "FR", displayMode = "regions",
         resolution = "provinces",
         width = 500, height = 400,
         colorAxis = "{colors:['#FFFFFF', '#0000FF']}"
)))
```